# 3 strings getting the same value when only assigned once

Tags: c, string, loops

OK so i dont know why this is happening.

heres the function that im dealing with.

```
while (map[x] && height <= box.size)
{
    width = 0;

    while (width <= box.size && height <= box.size)
    {
        if (map[x] == '.' || map[x] == 'x')
        {
            main_box[x] = 'x';
            n_of_fill++;
            width++;
        }
        if (map[x] == 'o')
            break;
        x++;
    }
    //To move a line down and start at the beginning of that line
    x = x + true_y + 1 - width;
    box.size = width;
    height++;
}
printf("3 \n\n%s\n\n%s\n\n%sfill = %i, width = %i, height = %i\n\n", main_box, map, tempmap, n_of_fill, width, height);
```

i get passed a map, a declare 2 other maps(tempmap and main_box). at the very beginning i set both tempmap and main_box to map, the function does what its told to do, (even tough its not right)... but now at the end of the code when i print all the maps, all the maps are the same!!??

when in the loop i only change map, and i dont set main_box or tempmap to map, so why are they all the same at the end of the function?!!

heres the full code (be cautious very long and very badly written code) 
http://pastebin.com/SdnJYPqP

any help would be great, and sorry if im being a complete and utter idiot...

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a debugger-as-a-service. If you're serious about programming you need to learn how to use a debugger, and then you will be able to step through the code, line by line while watching the value of all variables, and would be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Fyi, I don't see where you actually terminate the string after you fill it.

Comment: That is not a function.

Comment: I don't understand why you have the condition `height <= box.size` in the inner `while` loop (where neither `height` nor `box.size` are altered) when you have already tested that in the outer `while` loop.

Comment: If `tempmap` and `main_box` are pointers, and you set them to `map`, then all 3 pointers point to the same thing. There's only one array, and modifying it through any of those pointers will modify that array.

Comment: typo on my part with that double test.. sorry bout that, im not using stack overflow as a debugger service all im asking is why does it do that, why do all the strings end up the same, not "fix my code", your right ts not a function, sorry

Comment: thank you barmar, that was very stupid of me...

Comment: when asking a question of the type: `why does this not work?`  post code that cleanly compiles.  The snip of code that is posted has no context, and is missing a few key comments to indicate what is trying to be accomplished at each step in the code,  We are not mind readers.

Comment: it is highly frowned upon to post links to code.  Rather post a short, complete code that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: when coding, use variable names that are meaningful.  Variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both)

Comment: much better to  use `#include <stdbool.h>` than define your own boolean types

Comment: the referenced code has the line `fd = open(argv[` sitting between the functions: `ft_putstr()`  and `substring()`.   So the referenced code does not compile.  Suggest fixing the code so it does compile AND posting the code as part of the question rather than at some external web page.

Comment: the referenced code is missing the #include statements for the function: `open()`  Those missing statements are: `#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`   I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Answer (score 1):

I was being foolish. `main_box` and `tempmap` are pointers to `map` so when I change `map` and called all the others it was calling the same thing. thanks for the help! credit to barmar